# How Do I Get Started With Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Are there any good resources to get started with Spring Boot? Any good tutorials, blogs or books?

Comment: Please review questions that are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is specifically asking for a an off-site resource (#4), which is considered off-topic and inappropriate for SO.

Comment: Yes, try searching in this website `Google.com`

Comment: https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with Spring Boot, but assuming you want to build a web application, you can try visiting the official [Getting Started - Building an Application with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) guide.